# Spritesheet performance using canvas vs div + js

Tags: performance, html, canvas, sprite

I would like to know, does anybody have any experience what would be better:

1.) Using spritesheet and drawing it on canvas element.

2.) Using spritesheet with normal div and moving spritesheet via js or css.

Thanks, Luka

Comment: Canvas is more flexible, but don't bother learning canvas if you just want to play a spritesheet. Both will play a spritesheet without much stress on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving sprite-sheets with CSS is generally faster as most of the logic is done internally by the browser in compiled code, while doing it in JavaScript adds an overhead due to JavaScript itself.

You won't be able to avoid JavaScript completely of course, but reducing the amount of calls through JavaScript helps performance (in general, and this is also why you probably want to avoid jQuery for this specific purpose as jQuery comes with an overhead of its own).

With canvas you have more options in terms of altering the sprite-sheet, but if you don't need this I would recommend you use CSS and plain JavaScript where needed.